# How do I add linebreaks to comments?

Tags: support, comments

The help says that < br/ > style linebreaks can be added to a comment by inserting two spaces after the line in question. I tried it and can't make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work with comments, just answers and questions. You can also just use `<br/>`, BTW;  double new lines actually create a new paragraph, I think, rather than a carrier return/line feed.

Comment: Ah, right, the help is a bit ambiguous. The "Linebreak" stuff comes below a block about comment markdown, but now I see the comment stuff is in a yellow box and the linebreak aspect falls below that.